# Unresponsive Dock Icons over Applications

Tags: themes, startup, extension, helpfile, dash-to-dock

I don't know how to explain, but I was trying a lot of extensions and then lastly tried an extension. Now my desktop looks like this. I have rebooted my PC and also turned extensions off, yet it looks like this.

[image: Help Needed!]

The extension I have tried: [Material You Color Theming](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5236/material-you-color-theming/)

Comment: Are you sure it’s all disabled ? Open the Extension Manager and check [this button](https://imgur.com/a/rnM4S5g).

Comment: Hm... I was afraid because it hadn't been after restarting. But then I have removed [Dash to Dock Animator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5222/dash-to-dock-animator/). Thank you @Zatigem

Comment: Thank you @karel for making thinks clear